# Custom subtraction in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to perform subtraction for the adjacent rows (say like in my case N3-N2,N4-N3 and so on) and update the result in new column (Vaccination Growth Rate)in excel. I have approximately 3000+ records which it is not possible to do it manually. Can somebody please suggest a solution or formula to this where I can get the entire subracted results updated in a single formula with iteration?

I have tried the formula as in the image below but showing as #NAME? error.

[image]

Comment: Write the formula `=N3-N2` on cell O3? Then, copy the formula and paste it all the way down.

Comment: You wont have to change the row numbers. When you copy the formula and paste it on O4, you will see that the formula will change to `=N4-N3`. Why is copy/paste of formula not okay for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @shahkalpesh suggested, use `=N3-N2` formula to `O2` cell then click to right bottom corner of `O2` cell then drag down till need. You can double click to right bottom corner and it will automatically fill formulas to all cells `(O column)` having data to `N` column.

[image]